# importing external script - inconsistent behaviour across browsers and local vs server

Tags: jquery, import

I have a strange problem.  To being with, I have to make the code work within an LMS (learning management system), so I do not have 100% control over everything.  I need to import js from an external server. I tried both statically and dynamically important the file. The code works great in the local no matter which browser I use.  When it is uploaded to the server, it only works in IE and Safari. However, it does not work in Chrome and FF.  So, I am really confused whether this is an (security) issue raised by the LMS (because it works in all browsers locally) or this is an issue about the browser (because it does not work in FF and Chrome on the server), or both?  What do you think?  **Also, everything works fine when I move the js file to the same server.**

Dynamically:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript("http://url.com/quiz_instructions_elc_webid.js", function(){
        alert("Running test.js");
    });

});
</script>
```

or Statically:

```
<script src="http://url.com/quiz_instructions_elc_webid.js"></script>
```

Comment: How are you importing the JS? Please show some code.

Comment: @Barmar I included the code, the behavior I described is the same for static or dynamic versions.

Comment: Is `url.com` the same domain as the one with the main script? If not, you'll run into problems due to the AJAX Same-Origin policy.

Comment: @Barmar different domain.  But, importing JS is a problem?  Why we do not run into this problem when we import using the google jquery url?

Comment: The static method should work, the dynamic one might not.

Comment: @Barmar but the problem is that static method is not working on the server with FF and Chrome.

Comment: Are there errors in the JS console?

Comment: @Barmar No. And, it works when I move the js file to the same domain.  But, I need to keep it in the other server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about importing a js file from a non-secure domain (http://) to a secure domain (https://).  Firefox and Chrome do not allow this by default.  This is the reason for the inconsistent behavior.  I hope this helps anyone else who run into a similar situation.